# Android how to rename File in internal storage

Tags: android, kotlin, image-gallery, internal-storage

I got one image file from Internal Storage, example name of file is name_image_old, i want rename become name_image_new. i have tried use function renameTO() but not working.
My code:

```
  private fun rename(from: File, to: File): Boolean {
        return from.parentFile.exists() && from.exists() && from.renameTo(to)
    }

val currentFile = File("/sdcard/currentFile.txt")
                val newFile = File("/sdcard/newFile.txt")

                if (rename(currentFile, newFile)) {
                    //Success
                    Log.i(TAG, "Success")
                } else {
                    //Fail
                    Log.i(TAG, "Fail")
                }
```

Comment: Show your code. As renameTo should work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51773785/how-to-rename-a-file-in-internal-storage

Comment: yes, i have tried use this code but still not working

Comment: If rename() returns false then which of the three was false? Wrong coding. Do the checks before you calll renameTo then you know what happens.

Comment: It does not make sense to check of the parent exists. Checking if the file exists is very good. But do it outside your function.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do this
 `fun File.rename(to:String):Boolean{ return renameTo(File(this.parentFile, to)) }`

Comment: Please follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -1):

**xin chào Xuân Đức Nguyễn**

renameTO() doesn't work in my environment. The solution is to skip the temporary file method alltogeher, since it doesn't seem to be possible to solve in any reasonable time frame.

so i suggest not use File.renameTo() method in Internal Storage environment. Renaming a file in this environment, can do: - Copy content of the old file to new file. - Delete old file. :)

Comment: I really don't know how to delete the file. Please share code to handle my question. Thank bro !

Comment: This is code for delete

File dir = getFilesDir();

File file = new File(dir, "filename");

boolean deleted = file.delete();

Comment: RenameTo works just fine as long as both paths are in the same mount point.  It only becomes a problem when renaming and moving between internal and external storage.

Comment: bro, file.delete();  not working

Comment: share your code

Comment: val currentFile = File("/sdcard/currentFile.txt")
                val newFile = File("/sdcard/newFile.txt")

                if (rename(currentFile, newFile)) {
                    //Success
                    Log.i(TAG, "Success")
                } else {
                    //Fail
                    Log.i(TAG, "Fail")
                }

  private fun rename(from: File, to: File): Boolean {
        return from.parentFile.exists() && from.exists() && from.renameTo(to)
    }

Comment: my code not working